# No push empty struct with gorm

Tags: go, struct, go-gorm

I would like to push sensor struct's with Gorm. But sensor struct's doesn't have always weather or spec1 present in the db.

```
type Weather struct {
    temp int `gorm:"type:int(11);null"`
}

type Data struct {
    index int `gorm:"type:int(11);null"`
    id    int `gorm:"type:int(11);null"`
}

type OtherSpec struct {
    otherSpec int `gorm:"type:int(11);null"`
}

type Sensor struct {
    *Data
    *Weather
    *OtherSpec
}
```

My goal is to push the sensor struct even if spec1 or weather are not present. 
But when i'm doing this things, gorm say:

```
Error 1054: Unknown column 'temp' in 'field list'
```

For example if weather is not require and the db doesn’t have these field, how i can say to gorm to do not push Weather. There exist `gorm:"-"` to ignore a field but I doesn’t want to ignore him always.

Comment: Does it work when the structs are not embedded? Like copy temp from Weather and paste it where *Wheather is in sensor and try that

Comment: Oh and make sure the column is present in your db

Comment: Yes it work if the column is present in db. But all the db doesn't have weather column. I would like with an environment variable to disable weather struct easily push. I doesn't want to have x structs differents : one with Spec1, weather an other with Spec1 and no weather, ...